# Seeking Advice on AIY Vision Kit Integration with Coral.ai USB Accelerator and Optimal YOLO Version

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, google-aiy

I am currently working on a project that involves integrating the AIY Vision Kit with the USB Accelerator from Coral.ai. I am aiming to enhance the performance of my computer vision application and am interested in leveraging YOLO (You Only Look Once) for object detection.

My specific query is related to the compatibility and optimization of YOLO with the AIY Vision Kit and Coral.ai USB Accelerator. I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations regarding the most suitable version of YOLO for this setup.

If you have prior experience or knowledge regarding the integration of the AIY Vision Kit and YOLO, your guidance would be invaluable. Any tips, best practices, or considerations to keep in mind during the integration process would be highly appreciated.